# How to bind keyboard keys in button WPF?

Tags: wpf

I am working on a calculator App on WPF.
I would like to ask How can I capture when the user press a key in keyboard?
Currently, This is my code I am working with. But when I test it, it does not work.

```
<Button x:Name="cmdKeyEqual" Command="{Binding cmdEqual}" IsDefault="{Binding ElementName=cmdKeyEqual}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="113" Margin="290,376,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" Style="{StaticResource SimpleButtonStyle}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.332,0.33">
    <KeyBinding 
        Key="Return"
        Command="{Binding cmdEqual}"              
        Modifiers="Control"
        />
</Button>
```

Additionaly, the content of the button is 'System.Windows.Input.Keybinding'

Thanks in Advance. Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `KeyBinding` on your `Window`'s or `UserControl`'s `InputBindings`, so that when the window/control is in focus, and you press the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, it will execute the command binding.

```
<Window ...>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding cmdEqual}" Modifiers="Control" />
</Window.InputBindings>
...
</Window>
```